# Trying to find results applicable to comparing and analyzing finite product $\prod_{} (x_i - 1)$ vs. $\prod_{} x_i$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, upper-lower-bounds

Mahler, using the GM-AM ineq, has that $$ {\prod_{}^k \ (x_i +y_i)}^{\dfrac{1}{k}} \ge \prod_{}^k \ (x_i)^{\dfrac{1}{k}} + \prod_{}^k \ (y_i)^{\dfrac{1}{k}} \quad\quad x_i,y_i>0 $$

For trying to compare $\prod_{}^k (x_i - 1)$ with $\prod_{}^k x_i$, and $y_i = 1, x_i := x_i - 1$ etc.. this gives

$$ {\prod_{}^k \ (x_i)}^{\dfrac{1}{k}} \ge \prod_{}^k \ (x_i - 1)^{\dfrac{1}{k}} + 1 $$
$$ {\prod_{}^k \ (x_i)} \ge ({\prod_{}^k \ (x_i - 1)^{\dfrac{1}{k}} + 1})^k $$
but the RHS seems messy due to the fractional exponents and I tried turning it into a binomial but that doesn't get rid of the exponents so it's not really more useful it seems.I've been trying to find other inequalities or results that are applicable. Have looked through lists like [ineq](https://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf) trying to find anything but can't find anything useful. Is there anyone who might have some insight?

Comment: What kind of estimate are you looking for? Even for two numbers can the difference $(a-1)(b-1) -ab = 1-a-b$ be arbitrarily large.

Comment: @MartinR I was trying to look at $\prod_{}^k ({p_i}^{a_i + 1} - 1)$ compared to $\prod_{}^k ({p_i}^{a_i + 1})$ .  Where $p_i$ is the ith prime factor of a number $n\in \mathbb N$ and $a_i$ is the multiplicity of $p_i$ in the factorization of n into primes

Comment: There's a reason we usually use `\frac` and not `\dfrac`. This is rather hard to read.

Comment: The ratio of the two products is $\prod_j\left(1-\frac1{x_i}\right)$. Is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Just for information, by writing $(x_i-1)^{\frac{1}{k}}$, implicitly we need to have $x_i - 1>0$. Then we obtain evidently that 
$$\prod_i (x_i-1) = \prod_i  \left( x_i(1-\frac{1}{x_i}) \right) =\prod_i  x_i \prod_i(1-\frac{1}{x_i}) <\prod_i  x_i $$

Comment: In addition to using \frac instead of \dfrac, often you can make fractional exponents more legible by using an in-line / for division instead of a fraction: $$\prod^k \ (x_i)^{1/k}$$ is easily read, even for weak-eyed old geezers like me.